# Need to sign a C# .exe

Tags: c#, windows, smartscreen

I developed an application in C#.
When I try to run it, the following Windows Smart Screen pop-up show up:

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khnF1.jpg)

Clicking on "Run Anyway", the program start without problem.
As I need to install this exe on more computer, will be better that the program run without show this pop-up.

Reading on google I figure out that I need a certificate for running the program.
Anyone could help me about how generate a certificate? I don't want to pay for one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want to pay you MUST install your CA (or your self-signed certificate) to ALL PC to run the setup. [How certificate Works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33VYnE7Bzpk)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just to be sure: I see that you linked a video that explain SSL, this is the same for .exe applications?

Comment: Yes the video explain how certificate work with SSL but the principle don't change. Put it simple a certificate is a file that have some properties and its trusted but a CA, your PC already has some CA (execute `certmgr.msc` and look on **Third-party Root Certification**), if you have a certificate issued by one of them no problem, otherwise you must install YOUR CA on every PC. A CA is another certificate that _certify_ the certificate :-). You can dig deeper with this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbMlPIgzTxc)